# PHP Regex: extract fields

Tags: php, regex

From this text which is 4 rows and **5 columns**:

```
   Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator             1    443   443  VARCHAR2
   Related Provider Number                           10   686   695  CHAR
   Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents     1    834   834  VARCHAR2
   Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract       25   1022  1029 NUMBER
```

What is the regex to extract columns 1, 2, 5? Like:

```
Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator|1|VARCHAR2
Related Provider Number|10|CHAR
Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents|1|VARCHAR2
Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract|25|NUMBER
```

Here's my not working regex `\s{4}([\w\s]*)`: https://regex101.com/r/uQxRzA/1/

**update**

The only assumption that can help is that column 1 doesn't have names with 2 or more spaces.

Comment: Is there any safe assumption we can take for the first column?

Comment: Are the values separated by tabs or spaces?

Comment: the column seperator look like does not have a equal space distance will be very hard to write anny regex or parsing code for this.

Comment: Matching from the end probably works (at least for the shown samples): https://regex101.com/r/0rUhcz/1

Comment: [`^\h{2,}((?:(?!\h{2})[\s\S])*)\h*(\S+)(?:\h*\S+){2}\h*(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uQxRzA/2/)?

Comment: ^([A-Za-z0-9 :-]+)\W+\s{4}([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z]+)

Comment: @ctwheels thanks this is the best solution so far. Can you please put it in an answer so I can make it the correct one?

Comment: @numediaweb I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/uQxRzA/2/)

```
^\h{2,}((?:(?!\h{2})[\s\S])*)\h*(\S+)(?:\h*\S+){2}\h*(\S+)
```

Replace

```
$1|$2|$3
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\h{2,}` Match 2 or more horizontal whitespace characters
- `((?:(?!\h{2})[\s\S])*)` Capture the following into capture group 1.
- `\h*` Any number of horizontal whitespace characters
- `(\S+)` Capture one or more non-whitespace characters into capture group 2
- `(?:\h*\S+){2}` Match the following exactly twice

  - `\h*` Match any number of horizontal whitespace characters
  - `\S+` Match one or more non-whitespace characters
- `\h*` Match any number of horizontal whitespace characters
- `(\S+)` Capture one or more non-whitespace characters into capture group 3

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to normalize the lines first then you can just split on more than 2 white spaces.

```
$string = 'Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator             1    443   443  VARCHAR2
   Related Provider Number                           10   686   695  CHAR
   Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents     1    834   834  VARCHAR2
   Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract       25   1022  1029 NUMBER';
$bits = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
foreach($bits as $bit) {
    print_r(preg_split('/\h{2,}/', trim($bit)));
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/uIpq2

or in your case change

```
print_r(preg_split('/\h{2,}/', trim($bit)));
```

into

```
$columns = preg_split('/\h{2,}/', trim($bit));
```

then `$columns[0]` is  column 1, `$columns[1]` is column 2, and `$columns[4]` is column 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = <<<INPUT
   Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator             1    443   443  VARCHAR2
   Related Provider Number                           10   686   695  CHAR
   Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents     1    834   834  VARCHAR2
   Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract       25   1022  1029 NUMBER
INPUT;

preg_match_all("/(.*?)([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)(\n|$)/", $input, $m);

print_r($m);

/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>    Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator             1    443   443  VARCHAR2

            [1] =>    Related Provider Number                           10   686   695  CHAR

            [2] =>    Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents     1    834   834  VARCHAR2

            [3] =>    Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract       25   1022  1029 NUMBER
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>    Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator             
            [1] =>    Related Provider Number                           
            [2] =>    Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents     
            [3] =>    Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract       
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 443
            [1] => 686
            [2] => 834
            [3] => 1022
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 443
            [1] => 695
            [2] => 834
            [3] => 1029
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => VARCHAR2
            [1] => CHAR
            [2] => VARCHAR2
            [3] => NUMBER
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

            [1] => 

            [2] => 

            [3] => 
        )

)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

> to extract columns 1, 2, 5

With `preg_split` and `preg_match` functions:

```
$text = 'Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator             1    443   443  VARCHAR2
   Related Provider Number                           10   686   695  CHAR
   Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents     1    834   834  VARCHAR2
   Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract       25   1022  1029 NUMBER';

$lines = preg_split('/\s*\n\s*/', $text);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    preg_match('/^(.+\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)$/', $line, $m);
    array_shift($m);
    echo implode('|', $m) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output:

```
Compliance: 7-Day RN Waiver Indicator|1|VARCHAR2
Related Provider Number|10|CHAR
Services: Speech Pathology Off-Site Residents|1|VARCHAR2
Staff Count: Food Service Worker - Contract|25|NUMBER
```